# How to show data from one elements to two column in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

Let see,

```
<item>    
        <name>A</name>
    </item>
      <item>
<name>B</name></item>
     <item>
     <name>C</name></item>
    <item>       
        <name>D</name></item>
     <item>
     <name>E</name></item>
    <item>
     <name>F</name></item>
     <item>
     <name>G</name></item>
```

Now I am looking for XSLT Transformation like;

```
A           B
C           D
E           F
G           H
```

I am looking to show "name" in two columns in html page.
thanks

Comment: I want to see this data in two columns.

Comment: That's not very precise. HTML output? How exactly should the columns look like?

Comment: LIKE <TABLE><TR><TD>A<TD><TD>B></TR><TR><TD>D<TD><TD>E></TR><TR><TD>F<TD><TD>G></TR></TABLE> THANKS...

Comment: voted to close, looks like a homework question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dividing the position by 2 and seeing if there is a remainder...

**XML Input**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <name>A</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>B</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>C</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>D</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>E</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>F</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>G</name>
    </item>
</items>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <table>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() mod 2 = 1]"/>
            </table>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[position() mod 2 = 1]">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[1]/name"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>A</td>
         <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>C</td>
         <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>E</td>
         <td>F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>G</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `not(position() mod 2 = 0)`, better `position() mod 2 = 1` . After all, there are only two possible values of `position() mod 2`.

Comment: Also, for better support for older browsers, when it is the case that `following-sibling::name[1]` is empty, output `&x160;`. Older browsers behaved very badly when a cell was truly empty.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin - Good point about `position() mod 2`.

Comment: pls accept my changes here. regards.

Comment: @ROOMY - I've edited my answer to match the modifications you made to the XML input in your question.